# PHP adding specific values into pre-existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$availAds[$imageFile] = array(
        'image' => $imageFile,
        'title' => $artDetails[0],
        'link' => $artDetails[1]
    );
```

and I have values that need to be added to the array and  assigned the same values based on there content:

```
        foreach($querytitle as $currentTitle  ):
    $titlearray =  $currentTitle->nodeValue ;
    array_push( $availArts,$titlearray );
    endforeach;
```

I'm using array_push and that adds it to the array fine, but I ened to be able to assign 'title' to $currentTitle.

Hope this makes sense, and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to the [php.net array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Simply put, you can add items to arrays in a few ways:

```
$array[] = "foo";      // add "foo" to the end of array (same as array_push)
$array[1] = "foo";     // add "foo" at array index 1
$array['foo'] = "bar"; // add "bar" at the "foo" index of array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$availArts[$currentTitle] = 'title';
```